# make google's SignInButton with rounded corners looking like a material button

Tags: android, material-design, google-play-services

**TLDR: I want to make Google's Sign In button look like a material button with rounded corner shape and keep the rest(Text, google icon by default).**
I have implemented Sign-in feature using FirebaseUI on [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). The button I am using is `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` and it looks like it is from google play dependency. This default design looks ugly to me and also its look is not consistent with my other buttons.
[image]
So, I want to make it look like this first one at [guide line document](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#color).
[image]

I tried to follow this guide line as applying `style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"` to the button to make it look like material design button. however, it makes it look awkward.
[image]

How am I supposed to make it look like other buttons(material button)?

This is dependencies that I am using. might be helpful to know.

```
// Firebase
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

// Firebase UI
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$firebase_ui_version"
// Google Play
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$play_services_auth_version"
// Material Desgin
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version" // 1.9.0
```

Comment: You can use the same branding guideline to design your custom button.

Comment: java, kotlin or flutter????

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal `textview` or `button` and customize it by adding `drawable` start and a selecter background with rounded corners.
I have used textview and then i can manage the signin process inside `onClick`.

1. **xml code**

```
      <Textview
        android:id="@+id/googleSignInBtn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/google_button_background"
        android:text="Sign in with Google" />
```

2. **Drawble selecter file**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape android:shape="rectangle" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/black"
        android:width="2dp"/>
       <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
```

Result will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I am also using Material design dependency over the app, I wanted to make the Google sign in button to be look like other regular buttons. So I took advice from @Meet Prajapati and @Laser.
Result in designing it by myself as following the branding guideline. These are the steps that I did *but no idea if this is the proper way to do it*.

list up colors that I am going to use for the button ex) stroke color, font color in both day time and night mode.

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#131314</color>
<color name="google_btn_neutral">#F2F2F2</color>
<color name="google_btn_font_night">#E3E3E3</color>
<color name="google_btn_font_day">#1F1F1F</color>
<color name="google_btn_stroke_day">#747775</color>
<color name="google_btn_stroke_night">#8E918F</color>
```

customize widget and theme overlay style from material design like below for each day time and night mode.
In `themes.xml` in `value` folder for day time mode.

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/google_btn_stroke_day</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Button">
    <item name="colorContainer">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/google_btn_font_day</item>
</style>
```

in `themes.xml` in `value-night` folder for night mode.

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/google_btn_stroke_night</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Button">
    <item name="colorContainer">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/google_btn_font_night</item>
</style>
```

extract "G" code from the asset I downloaded from [guideline doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#download-brand-icons) and save to `ic_google_sign_in_40` and place it under drawable folder.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="40"
    android:viewportHeight="40">

    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M12,10h20v20h-20z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M31.6,20.23C31.6,19.52 31.54,18.84 31.42,18.18H22V22.05H27.38C27.15,23.3 26.45,24.36 25.39,25.07V27.58H28.62C30.51,25.84 31.6,23.27 31.6,20.23Z"
        android:fillColor="#4285F4"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M22,30C24.7,30 26.96,29.1 28.62,27.58L25.39,25.07C24.49,25.67 23.35,26.02 22,26.02C19.4,26.02 17.19,24.26 16.4,21.9H13.06V24.49C14.71,27.76 18.09,30 22,30Z"
        android:fillColor="#34A853"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M16.4,21.9C16.2,21.3 16.09,20.66 16.09,20C16.09,19.34 16.2,18.7 16.4,18.1V15.51H13.06C12.39,16.86 12,18.39 12,20C12,21.61 12.39,23.14 13.06,24.49L16.4,21.9Z"
        android:fillColor="#FBBC04"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M22,13.98C23.47,13.98 24.79,14.48 25.82,15.47L28.69,12.6C26.96,10.99 24.7,10 22,10C18.09,10 14.71,12.24 13.06,15.51L16.4,18.1C17.19,15.74 19.4,13.98 22,13.98Z"
        android:fillColor="#E94235"/>
</vector>
```

add that icon and extra attribute values to make it look good fit on my app.

```
<Button // <- this will be inflated as MaterialButton in run time if you are using Material dependency
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in_with_google"
    style="@style/Widget.App.Button.GoogleButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_with_google"
    app:iconSize="40dp"
    app:iconTint="@null"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    app:iconPadding="0dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_google_sign_in_40"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_sign_up_with_email" />
```

Now it looks like below each on day time mode and night mode.
[image] for day time mode
[image] for night mode
Hope it might be right way and help some body in some way. Also I appreciate it if you leave any comment if it seems wrong at some point.